# Empty line in .Net File.WriteAllLines, is a bug?

Tags: c#, .net

all

This question is related to two methods in System.IO.File:

File.WriteAllLines and File.ReadAllLines

When I save a List[string] ListA by using

```
File.WriteAllLines("filename",ListA.ToArray());
```

There will be an empty line append to the output file.

So each time I load this file by calling `File.ReadAllLines`, I will always get one more empty line.

It's annoying, as I have to "remove" it manually each time.

Does anyone suffering same problem? And how you deal with it?

Thanks

Comment: are you sure that last item in `ListA` doesn't have `\n` char?

Comment: Are you sure that ListA doesn't contain an empty element?

Comment: Try outputting ListA.toArry to the console and see if it has any line breaks.

Comment: `toArray` seems like java, are you converting some code, seems like you missed something, How are the contents of ListA loaded/filled

Comment: By design, the last line will have a NewLine appended as well so it *looks* like there's an empty line at the bottom in any text editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, I can't reproduce that:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string[] lines = { "first", "second", "third" };

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            File.WriteAllLines("test.txt", lines);

            lines = File.ReadAllLines("test.txt");
            Console.WriteLine("Number of lines read: {0}", lines.Length);
        }
    }
}
```

It sounds like it's probably something to do with what you're *doing* with the lines... which you haven't told us.

Comment: I use List of string  and save as File.WriteAllLines("filename",ListA.toArry());

Comment: @DuSijun: Well there's no such method as `toArry` to I suspect this isn't the standard `List<T>`... or you're giving us the wrong code. You need to provide more context, but basically I don't think you should be blaming `File.WriteAllLines` or `File.ReadAllLines`.

Comment: Sorry for that is ListA.ToArray();

Comment: @DuSijun: Well then the problem is still somewhere else - just creating a list from an array and then converting the list back to an array isn't going to add entries. Please try to show the problem in a short but complete program - like mine, but showing the error.

Comment: Thanks, for your reply, I think there are something wrong with my data,that's my problem but not the WritAllLines.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11689337/net-file-writealllines-leaves-empty-line-at-the-end-of-file

Comment: @JonSkeet an answer to another question contradicts this conclusion: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11689503/3195477

Comment: @DaveInCaz: I think it depends on what you mean by an empty line. There will be a line break at the very end of the file, yes. But the OP is calling ReadAllLines which handles that fine, without adding a spurious line. The answer you linked to doesn't contradict that as far as I can see.